How does Float32 in GeoPackage raster work
The more general question I'm asking myself is: What (raster) datatype should I use for a GIS-based game I am making in non-gis software: GeoTiff+GeoParquet or GeoPackage? The software (Godot) has support for EXR and PNG, and the GeoPackage spec says it should be in either PNG or JPEG format.
Ok, now it becomes interesting. So I've put a raster with Float32 in a GeoPackage using QGIS, and opened it in db browser, guess what its hexdump looks like:

49492a00080000000c00000103000100
00000001000001010300010000000001
00000201030001000000200000000301
03000100000005000000060103000100
00000100000011010400010000009e00
00001501030001000000010000001601
03000100000000010000170104000100
00006e5900001c010300010000000100
00003d01030001000000010000005301
03000100000003000000000000008000
0003722001010400302110a82c1e0b03
82b006d05204210038888e61e3b888f2
1a3e8690222418a10e22448891a22488

the 49492a00 looks like a tiff header to me... So basically the real question is: Can someone confirm that QGIS/GDAL actually stores tiffs in the geopackage blob, contrary to the spec?

You have a link to GDAL 1.10 documentation. Current v. 3.9 documentation mentions TIFF and
Tiled gridded coverage data https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html. The GeoPackage standards can be found from https://www.ogc.org/standard/geopackage/.

Since it is an extension that is used, the ogc geopackage standard is not used here. I read the gdal docs, but they are confusing as well; here they only mention PNG/JPG/WebP formats, it is all explained a bit earlier: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#tiled-gridded-coverage-data

Extension mechanism belongs to core GeoPackage and accepted extensions like this one https://docs.ogc.org/is/17-066r2/17-066r2.html have the same OGC standard status than the core. I would say that GDAL is implementing the OGC GeoPackage standard with 32 bit raster data just like OGC wants. The OGC vocubulary may not be the best possible. Core standard defined only "tiles" and "features", and the extension for elevation-like data got the name "OGC GeoPackage Extension for Tiled Gridded Coverage Data". The tiles of the core standard are actually also tiled, gridded coverage data.

Each GDAL document page has an "Edit on GitHub" link in the top-right corner. When the documenation feels confusing, please improve it. I can see that the writer has tried to clarify that PNG/JPEG/WebP in "Tiled rasters" are for 8-bit data: "This section only applies for raster of Byte data type.". So that section does not apply for 16 and 32 bit data.

thanks for clarifying comments!

The answer is that an extension is used, which can be found in the gpkg_extensions table:

Then in the spec that it links to, you can find:

integers have PNG encoding
floats have TIFF encoding, with some constraints:

LZW compression
1 band
1 image



So indeed it is a tiff and it does follow the specification!
